# Passing InputBox entry generates Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: excel, vba

An input box comes up to enter an item name, example "Test Item". Then another input box comes up to enter a cost, example "13.2". The code is designed to find the first empty cell in column B and enter the Item and then offset one column to the right and enter the Cost.

I am getting Run-time error '424': Object required on

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select.FormulaR1C1 = Item

```
  Sub AddSWItem()
      Dim Item As String
      Dim Cost As String

      Item = InputBox("Item")
      Cost = InputBox("Cost")

      Range("B11").Select
      Selection.End(xlDown).Select
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Item
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Cost
  End Sub
```

Comment: Verify that ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) is not null.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I verified, it is selecting cell B13 which is where it should be.

Comment: Well, verify the whole sentence for null. "Object required" means that there is a null reference in your sentence.

Comment: I mean I asked the question because I'm not sure how to go about identifying what is wrong with it. When I click the button each input box comes up correctly and I enter the item and cost and then it debugs when it is supposed to enter it into the cell. It has the correct cell selected I'm just not sure why it won't enter the data there.

Comment: Actually think I figured it out. Just had to move some stuff around. Thanks for the feedback Oscar. Corrected the code.

Comment: item is not a formmula, change to `ActiveCell.value= Item`. Formulas begin with '='

Answer (score 2):

I guess you figured out what you wanted but here are some notes on alternative coding.

Using VBA you can address cells directly and not use the active cells. The active cells are useful when you want the user to define where the results will be placed. If the locations are known you can use the Range object.

Below are several examples. Also include are some standard VBA error logic and debug techniques.

```
        Sub AddSWItem()
        On Error GoTo Local_err
            Dim Item As String
            Dim Cost As String
            Dim rng As Range

            Item = InputBox("Item")
            Cost = InputBox("Cost")

            ' QA code here

            Set rng = Range("B11")
            rng(1, 0) = Item
            rng(0, 2) = Cost

            ' or use direct entry

            rng(2, 0) = InputBox("Item 2")
            rng(1, 2) = InputBox("Cost 2")

            ' or

            Range("B11")(3, 0) = InputBox("Item 3")
            Range("B11")(2, 2) = InputBox("Cost 3")

       Local_Exit:
            Exit Sub
       Local_err:
            MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
            Resume Local_err ' Ctrl-Break to debug at this point
            Resume ' Right click -set next statement here to resume on failed line
        End Sub
```